# After the installation process When the server is running, nothing is displayed on the page myddleware

Tags: docker, installation, server-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAmbb.jpg)
After the installation process When the server is running, nothing is displayed on the page myddleware

Comment: When the door is open, it gets cold inside.  When I am swimming, I get wet .. See?  I can do it too ..